# Deploy hosting only to custom domain?

Tags: firebase-hosting

I have my custom domain in Firebase as well as the pre-generated domains:

```
myproject-cb169.web.app
myproject-cb169.firebaseapp.com
www.myproject.ca
```

Now via CLI I want to deploy my website but only to my custom domain ([www.myproject.ca](http://www.myproject.ca)). How do I edit the rules/targets for this?

My current/default `firebase.json` hosting settings:

```
"hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "rewrites": [{
      "source": "**",
      "destination": "/index.html"
    }],
```

Answer (score 1):

The URLs you specify are all pointing to the same instance of the exact same data.  There is no way to make the change only available on your custom domain.

If you want people to use only your custom domain, be sure to promote that one and not either of the default generated ones.